# Paginating with Firestore - keeps bringing back same last ten documents

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination on Firestore. I have a 100 docs.

The page I render kicks off with a limit of the first ten documents and then when I hit the next button I want another ten and so on until all 100 documents appear. The first click brings down the next 10 so I get 20 original docs as I would expect. The next click though and all subsequent ones keep bringing the down the same last 10 documents i.e. it doesn't bring down new docs just duplicates. any ideas? Pretty new to coding... Many thanks..

```
var first = db.collection("trails").orderBy('title').limit(10);
   first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
    documentSnapshots.docs.forEach(doc => {
        //function to display in the HTML
        console.log(doc.data(), doc.id);
      addTrails(doc.data(), doc.id);
    });

    var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];
    console.log(lastVisible)



    //select button for more trails to appear
    const moreTrails = document.querySelector('.more-trails');
    moreTrails.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('click')

    var next = db.collection("trails").orderBy('title').startAfter(lastVisible).limit(10);
     next.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
      documentSnapshots.docs.forEach(doc => {
          //function to display in the HTML
          console.log(doc.data(), doc.id);
        addTrails(doc.data(), doc.id);
      });
    })
  })
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show all the details of the query you're doing that doesn't work the way you expect.  For example, we can't see the value of `lastVisible` and we don't know what actual data you're working with, so it's impossible for us to know what you expect the query to yield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right, you are getting the first 10 and the next 10 correctly, but from there on you are getting the same result, aka from 10 to 19.

If that is the case I think you are not updating the value from `lastVisible`.

Try doing something like this and see how it goes:

```
next.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
    lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];
        documentSnapshots.docs.forEach(doc => {
           //function to display in the HTML
           console.log(doc.data(), doc.id);
           addTrails(doc.data(), doc.id);
        });
     })
```